# Variable como nombre de tabla PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy tratando de crear un calendario con `fullcalendar`, pero la tabla para ese calendario es creada de acuerdo al usuario y pasada en la URL y la obtengo con $_GET.

El problema es cuando intento crear los eventos, ya intente con **mysql_escape_string**, ya intenté con separar la sentencia en otra variable y despues ponerla en el `prepare`...

He aquí el código:

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$tabla = $_GET['tabla'];
try{
    
    $db = new PDO (); //solo borre las credenciales de la conexion
    $accion = (isset($_GET['accion']))?$_GET['accion']:'leer';

    switch($accion){
        case 'agregar':
            $tabla = "`".str_replace("`","``",$tabla)."`";
            $sentenciaSQL = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(title,descripcion,color,textColor,start,end)VALUES(:title,:descripcion,:color,:textColor,:start,:end)");
            $respuesta = $sentenciaSQL->execute(array(
                "title" => $_POST['title'],
                "descripcion" => $_POST['descripcion'],
                "color" => $_POST['color'],
                "textColor" => $_POST['textColor'],
                "start"=> $_POST['start'],
                "end"=>$_POST['end']
            ));
            echo json_encode($respuesta);
            break;
        case 'modificar':
            $sentenciaSQL = $db->prepare("UPDATE eventos_tienda_galletas SET
                title=:title,
                descripcion=:descripcion,
                color=:color,
                textColor=:textColor,
                start=:start,
                end=:end
                WHERE id=:ID");

            $respuesta=$sentenciaSQL->execute(array(
                "ID"=>$_POST['id'],
                "title"=>$_POST['title'],
                "descripcion"=>$_POST['descripcion'],
                "color"=>$_POST['color'],
                "textColor"=>$_POST['textColor'],
                "start"=>$_POST['start'],
                "end"=>$_POST['end']
            ));
            echo json_encode($respuesta);
            break;
        case 'eliminar':
            $respuesta = false;
            if(isset($_POST['id'])){
                $sentenciaSQL = $db ->prepare("DELETE FROM eventos_tienda_galletas WHERE id=:ID");
                $respuesta = $sentenciaSQL->execute(array("ID"=>$_POST['id']));
            }
            echo json_encode($respuesta);
            break;
        default:
            $sentenciaSQL= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");
            $sentenciaSQL->execute(array("tipo"=>$tipo));
            $resultado = $sentenciaSQL ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo json_encode($resultado);
            break;
    }

} catch (Exception $err) {
    die("Error!: ".$err);
}
```

El unico que funciona es la acción `default`.

¿Podrian ayudarme como puedo adaptarlo?

Este codigo se manda a llamar por jquery con el uso de la biblioteca de fullcalendar de esta forma :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#eventos').fullCalendar({
    header: {},
    customButtons: {
      Miboton: {
        text: "Buton 1",
        click: function() {
          alert("Funcion del boton");
        }
      }
    },
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
      limpiarFormulario()
      $("#txtFecha").val(date.format());
      $("#ModalEventos").modal('show');
    },

    events: 'eventos.php?tabla=eventos_<?php echo $table ?>',

    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
      //h2
      $("#tituloEvento").html(calEvent.title);

      //mostrar la informacion del evento
      $("#txtDescripcion").val(calEvent.descripcion);
      $("#txtID").val(calEvent.id);
      $("#txtTitulo").val(calEvent.title);
      $("#txtColor").val(calEvent.color);
      FechaHora = calEvent.start._i.split(" ");
      $("#txtFecha").val(FechaHora[0]);
      $("#txtHora").val(FechaHora[1]);
      $("#ModalEventos").modal('show');
    },
    editable: true,
    eventDrop: function(calEvent) {
      $("#txtID").val(calEvent.id);
      $("#txtTitulo").val(calEvent.title);
      $("#txtColor").val(calEvent.color);
      $("#txtDescripcion").val(calEvent.descripcion);
      var fechaHora = calEvent.start.format().split("T");
      $("#txtFecha").val(fechaHora[0]);
      $("#txtHora").val(fechaHora[1]);
      RecolectarDatosGUI();
      EnviarInformacion('modificar', NuevoElemento, true);
    }
  });
});
```

y de esta forma hacemos las acciones:

```javascript
<script>
var NuevoElemento;
$('#btnAgregar').click(function() {
  RecolectarDatosGUI();
  EnviarInformacion('agregar', NuevoElemento);

});
$('#btnEliminar').click(function() {
  RecolectarDatosGUI();
  EnviarInformacion('eliminar', NuevoElemento);

});
$('#btnModificar').click(function() {
  RecolectarDatosGUI();
  EnviarInformacion('modificar', NuevoElemento);

});

function RecolectarDatosGUI() {
  NuevoElemento = {
    id: $('#txtID').val(),
    title: $('#txtTitulo').val(),
    start: $('#txtFecha').val() + " " + $('#txtHora').val(),
    color: $('#txtColor').val(),
    descripcion: $('#txtDescripcion').val(),
    textColor: "#FFFFFF",
    end: $('#txtFecha').val() + " " + $('#txtHora').val()
  };
}

function EnviarInformacion(accion, objEvento, modal) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'eventos.php?accion=' + accion,
    data: objEvento,
    success: function(msg) {
      if (msg) {
        $('#eventos').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        if (!modal) {
          $("#ModalEventos").modal('toggle');
        }

      } else {
        alert("2 Ocurrio un error.");
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Ocurrio un error.");
    }
  });
}

$('.clockpicker').clockpicker();


function limpiarFormulario() {
  $("#txtID").val('');
  $("#txtTitulo").val('');
  $("#txtColor").val('');
  $("#txtDescripcion").val('');
}
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde estás definiendo la variable `$accion`? Parece que solo falta eso.

Comment: ¿Eso donde va a parar?  ¿Es una petición ajax con GET? ¿quien recibe y maneja ese json? ¿porque pretendes devolver una simple eliminación/agregación/manipulación en lugar de toda la tabla de nuevo? ¿para que sirve el `tipo` de tu execute() en el default?

Comment: Disculpenme chicos, ya agregue mas codigo y detalles

Comment: Si va a un fullcalendar entiendo que debes reenviarle toda la tabla despues de cada accion que no sea default, y que luego haga un reload, refresh o lo que sea que haga el fullcalendar para recargar los eventos.

Comment: Si pero el nombre de la tabla no es fija, es creada por el usuario en un formulario y se recibe con $GET, asi como ya lo mencioné, no puedo incluirla en el INSERT INTO

Comment: Ya agregue el codigo completo

Comment: Un problema es que siempre esperas recibir la tabla por $_GET, pero no estás enviando el parámetro en `url: 'eventos.php?accion='+accion,` (función EnviarInformación).

Comment: Otro problema es que estás duplicando ID de elementos en cada evento y [los ID deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Comment: @Triby Tienes alguna sugerencia para enviar la tabla en el url:? suponiendo que el nombre de la tabla es "eventos_<?php echo $table ?>"

Comment: Donde generas los eventos tienes `events: 'eventos.php?tabla=eventos_<?php echo $table ?>',` y puedes crear una variable global antes de mostrar los eventos `var table = 'eventos_<?php echo $table; ?>';` y después la usas para las otras peticiones.

Comment: oh ya, excelente, muchas gracias amigo, ya me salió :D